# Zip in Python: How to return tuples instead of a zip object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zip

I am currently using Python 3.7.3 and am relatively new. My understanding was that the zip() function returns a list of tuples, however in practice I have found it returns a 'zip' object. Is there a way that I can get this function to return a list of tuples or a similar function that can accomplish my purpose?
Thanks so much!

I don't know if that was automatic or a mod did that, but thank you!

Comment: "My understanding was that the zip() function returns a list of tuples" your undersanding is incorrect. `zip` returns a `zip` objet `zip` is a class. This object is an iterator, so just create a list out of it

Comment: `zip` *used* to return a list of tuples, in Python 2.

Comment: You only need the `list` function to turn a zip object into the corresponding list

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is convert it to a list.

```
list(zip(....))
```